# In spring MVC, Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'modelform' available as request attribute. Please advise

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

HomeController :

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/resultmodel",method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
        public ModelAndView add(@ModelAttribute("homeDTO") homeDTO hdto,Model model) {
            ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("resultmodel","homeDTO", new homeDTO());
            model.addAttribute("homeDTO", hdto.getUserName());

            return view;
    }
```

Result Jsp

```
<h1>Result model</h1>
<form:form action="resultmodel" method="post"  modelAttribute="modelform">  <!--  -->
<form:input type="text" path="homeDTO"/>
<input type="submit">
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

modelattribute name is same as of@modelattribute still getting the error

Comment: Sorry, where is the definition of modelform? Blind try, don't you need to use el syntax?

Comment: sorry 
<form:form action="resultmodel" method="post"  modelAttribute="homeDTO">

Comment: Do you have the @Controller and@ControllerAdvice annotation in your class?